# How to detect an empty paragraph in python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

Given a document containing a paragraph

```
d = docx.Document()
p = d.add_paragraph()
```

I expected the following technique to work every time:

```
if len(p._element) == 0:
    # p is empty
```

OR

```
if len(p._p) == 0:
    # p is empty
```

(Side question, what's the difference there? It seems that `p._p is p._element` in every case I've seen in the wild.)

If I add a style to my paragraph, the check no longer works:

```
>>> p2 = d.add_paragraph(style="Normal")
>>> print(len(p2._element))
1
```

Explicitly setting `text=None` doesn't help either, not that I would expect it to.

So how to I check if a paragraph is empty of content (specifically text and images, although more generic is better)?

**Update**

I messed around a little and found that setting the style apparently adds a single `pPr` element:

```
>>> p2._element.getchildren()
[<CT_PPr '<w:pPr>' at 0x7fc9a2b64548>]
```

The element itself it empty:

```
>>> len(p2._element.getchildren()[0])
0
```

But more importantly, it is not a run.

So my test now looks like this:

```
def isempty(par):
    return sum(len(run) for run in par._element.xpath('w:r')) == 0
```

I don't know enough about the underlying system to have any idea if this is a reasonable solution or not, and what the caveats are.

**More Update**

Seems like I need to be able to handle a few different cases here:

```
def isempty(par):
    p = par._p
    runs = p.xpath('./w:r[./*[not(self::w:rPr)]]')
    others = p.xpath('./*[not(self::w:pPr) and not(self::w:r)] and '
                     'not(contains(local-name(), "bookmark"))')
    return len(runs) + len(others) == 0
```

This skips all `w:pPr` elements and runs with nothing but `w:rPr` elements. Any other element, except bookmarks, whether in the paragraph directly or in a run, will make the result non-empty.

Comment: Not overly familiar with the docx module but shouldn't you be checking the text property of the paragraph and not just the paragraph object? [Paragraph.text](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph.text): `String formed by concatenating the text of each run in the paragraph`.

Comment: @Alan. No, because it can contain images. Looking at the XML child nodes ought to be a better idea.

Comment: @Alan. Although that does make me think it might be a better idea to iterate over all runs, and make sure they are all empty instead of just checking one run.

Comment: Yes, wasn't sure if you were just checking the text or if you were after any visible content.

Comment: Images are stored as `Inline Shapes` in the underlying docx format. I saw there's details of how to add a Shape to a run but no idea how you would test for the presence of one!

Comment: @Alan. The run (child of `par._p`) would have a child element. I don't care what the child is. I just want it to be empty

Comment: @Alan. I've made an update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<w:p>` element can have any of a large number of children, as you can see from the XML Schema excerpt here: http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/schema/ct_p.html (see the CT_P and EG_PContent definitions).

In particular, it often has a `w:pPr` child, which is where the style setting goes.

So your test isn't very reliable against false positives (if being empty is considered positive).

I'd be inclined to use `paragraph.text == ''`, which parses through the runs.

A run can be empty (of text), so the mere presence of a run is not proof enough. The actual text is held in a `a:t` (text) element, which can also be empty. So the `.text` approach avoids all those low-level complications for you and has the benefit of being part of the API so much, much less likely to change in a future release.

Comment: What about images? What happens if I get a run with a picture but no text?

Comment: I've made yet another update. This time I think my xpath expression takes into account what you said.