# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Paragraph' and 'str'. Replace words after a paragraph in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx, paragraph, find-replace

I want to Find and replace text which is only after a paragraph.

Text in my word document:

[image: image of text in my word document]

As you can see, I want to replace the Word Ocean which is at the end.
So, I want to replace the word 'Ocean' which is only after a paragraph

My Code so far:-

```
from docx import Document

document = Document('rea.docx')

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if paragraph+'Ocean' in paragraph.text:
        paragraph.text.replace("Sea")
```

I want to replace the Words which are after a paragraph.
I also want to replace words which are after two paragraphs like this :

[image: image of word after two paragraphs]

I also want to replace words which are after three paragraphs like this:

[image: image of word after three paragraphs]

How can i Write a code which can replace words which are after a paragraph and after two paragraphs and which are after three paragraphs?

[image]

in the above Picture, I want to replace :-

Ocean:sea
Plants:Seeds
Flowers:Plants

So, I want to replace Only specific words if a paragraph precedes it

There are so many words i should replace if more than a paragraph precedes it.

My:you

Bone:Muscle

Speaker:Magnet

Bin:Dustbin

Pen:Pencil

***Note:- I want to replace the above words only if more than a paragraph precedes it.***

So, the output will look like:
[image]

Comment: The images help

Comment: I said that i want to replace a word with another word. that word should not be in paragraph, it should be the first word after a paragraph

Comment: See all the three images. I want to replace the last word

Comment: Your if statement is currently trying to add 'Ocean' to the end of a paragraph, then checking if the result of `paragraph+'Ocean'` is true, then checking if that true/false value is in `paragraph`

Comment: That is not what i meant. Sorry. But my code doesnt make any sense

Comment: I want to replace the last word 'Ocean'.

Comment: I want to replace any word which is after one line in word document

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you had images at first. That was all I really needed. Too much bold text :)

Comment: No Problem. But Please Try to answer the question.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Do you actually care how many paragraphs precede it, or is it just about finding a paragraph which only contains the text 'Ocean'? If the latter, replacing your if statement with `if paragraph.text == 'Ocean':` should do the job

Comment: I expect The last word 'Ocean' should Be replaced with the word 'sea'. Not all 'Ocean' words in the document but only the last 'Ocean' word.

Comment: I care how many paragraphs precede it.

Comment: Is it just the last one, or any single-word paragraph that's preceded by an empty one?

Comment: any single-word paragraph that's preceded by an empty one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python to Find-replace a string and Create Two Paragraphs Before String in Words Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72526415/python-to-find-replace-a-string-and-create-two-paragraphs-before-string-in-words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task appears to be to detect an empty paragraph followed by a non-empty paragraph.

As I found out some time ago, checking for empty paragraphs is non-trivial in a word document: [How to detect an empty paragraph in python-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51217113/2988730). However, if you're only dealing with text, it's made simple by the `text` attribute. You can therefore set a flag whenever an empty is found, and replace text whenever the flag is set.

Let's say you have a dictionary of replacements:

```
replacements = {
    'Ocean': 'sea',
    'Plants': 'Seeds',
    'Flowers': 'Plants',
}
```

Notice that order is important: if you replace `Flowers` with `Plants` before `Plants` with `Seeds`, you will run into a problem. I'm assuming you're using Python >= 3.6, where regular dictionaries are ordered.

You have a couple of options going forward. One is to make a function that replaces a single word in the document, and call it for each word:

```
def replace(doc, target, replacement):
    prev_is_empty = False
    for par in doc.paragraphs:
        if par.text == '':
            c = True
        elif prev_is_empty:
            par.text = par.text.replace(target, replacement)
            prev_is_empty = False

for item in replacements.items():
    replace(document, *item)
```

Another option is to replace the whole dictionary at once for each relevant paragraph:

```
prev_is_empty = False
for par in document.paragraphs:
    if par.text == '':
        prev_is_empty = True
    elif prev_is_empty:
        s = par.text
        for item in replacements.items():
            s = s.replace(*item)
        par.text = s
        prev_is_empty = False
```

Comment: @Noob-Programmer Also, don't worry about the number of empty paragraphs: any number >1 is OK. What I'm more concerned with is (a) what output you expect, and (b) what happens if you have three non-empty paragraphs, the last two preceded by an empty one?

Comment: elif par_is_empty:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'par_is_empty' referenced before assignment

Comment: If i want to replace words only if >=2 paragraphs precedes the word. what can i do ?

Comment: @Noob-Programmer. Then you count the paragraphs.

Comment: How can i create a paragraph in the place of any word ?--------------If i see any word, then a paragraph should be created before the word.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72526415/python-to-find-replace-a-string-and-create-two-paragraphs-before-string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72517126/python-to-create-a-find-replace-dictionary-from-a-word-vba-macro

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72535824/python-to-make-the-first-letter-capital-at-the-start-of-every-paragraph-and-afte

Comment: `elif par_is_empty` - did you mean `elif prev_is_empty`?