# Python to get no. of characters of files ending with .docx from a directory and divide each file's characters by 65 and save them to an Excel File

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, character, python-docx

I have more than 100 Files in a directory. Every File Endswith .docx

I want to write a python code which gets the characters count for each and every word document and divide each document's no. of characters by 65 and store them to a excel sheet.

code of how i want:-

```
import python word document library
directory = /xyz/folder

for files in directory:
    if files .endswith(.docx):
        get character-count for each and every File
        divide each file's character count by 65
    with open myfile.xlsx as writable form:
        format:- name of the file, final character count of file
         do this to all files in a directory that endswith .docx
```

Note:- final character count of files means no. of characters with spaces divided by 65

[Image1 (click on this link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLdIU.png)

Image of my files.

get character count and divide by 65 and save to excel

[Image2 (click on this link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaSJF.png)

I think Python-docx can be used for this. or any other library is also ok.

I want no. of characters with spaces divided by 65

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```py
# uses python-docx package
import docx
import os

charCounts = {}
directory = os.fsencode('.')
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".docx"):
        #filename = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        doc = docx.Document(filename)
        chars = sum(len(p.text) for p in doc.paragraphs)
        charCounts[filename] = chars / 65

# uses openpyxl package
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws.cell(row=1, column=2, value='File Name')
ws.cell(row=1, column=4, value='chars/65')
for i, x in enumerate(charCounts):
    ws.cell(row=i + 3, column=2, value=x)
    ws.cell(row=i + 3, column=4, value=charCounts[x])
path = './charCounts.xlsx'
wb.save(path)
```

Sample Environment:

```
Files ending in `.docx`:
Doc1.docx
    contains 'This file has some characters.'
Doc2.docx
    contains the concatenation of 77 copies of 'This file has some characters.\n'
Empty Doc.docx
    contains no characters
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I have files which endswith .docx and .doc. i want no. of characters/65 for .docx and .doc and save in excel file.

Comment: I also want to print the total in the chars/65 coloumn at the end.

Comment: To print the total in the chars/65 column, just insert this line after the final for loop: `ws.cell(row=len(charCounts) + 3, column=4, value=sum(charCounts.values()))`. Your question about `.doc` files is really a separate question, as python-docx does not support the `.doc` format. If you decide to ask a new question specifically about analyzing `.doc` files, feel free to drop a link to it in the comments here and I will take a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72859105/python-to-get-no-of-characters-of-files-ending-with-docx-and-doc-from-a-direc

Comment: In excel sheet, i want to remove file name extensions.

Comment: My new Question Link:--      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72859105/python-to-get-no-of-characters-of-files-ending-with-docx-and-doc-from-a-direc

Comment: Got it - please see my answer to your new question.