# How to get no. of characters of files ending with .docx and .doc from a directory and divide each file's characters by 65 and save them to an xlsx

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, python-docx, doc

I have a folder of many word document files ending with .doc and .docx.

This code is working only for .docx
I want this for .doc also

```
import docx
import os

charCounts = {}
directory = os.fsencode('.')
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".docx"):
        #filename = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        doc = docx.Document(filename)
        chars = sum(len(p.text) for p in doc.paragraphs)
        charCounts[filename] = chars / 65

# uses openpyxl package
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws.cell(row=1, column=2, value='File Name')
ws.cell(row=1, column=4, value='chars/65')
for i, x in enumerate(charCounts):
    ws.cell(row=i + 3, column=2, value=x)
    ws.cell(row=i + 3, column=4, value=charCounts[x])
    ws.cell(row=len(charCounts) + 3, column=4, value=sum(charCounts.values()))
path = './charCounts.xlsx'
wb.save(path)
```

Images:-

I have files like these.
[image]

I want them to happen like these:

[image]

Notice two things here.

File names in excel sheet have been arranged number-wise.

Second thing is in excel sheet, the file extensions have been removed. I want it Like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an update to the code in your question which will do what I believe you have asked:

```py
# uses python-docx package
import docx
import os

# uses pywin32 package
import win32com.client as win32
from win32com.client import constants
app = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')

charCounts = {}
fileDir = '.' # Put the path of the directory to be searched here
os.chdir(fileDir)
cwd = os.getcwd()
directory = os.fsencode(cwd)
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.startswith('TEMP_CONVERTED_WORD_FILE_'):
        continue
    filenameOrig = None
    if filename.endswith(".doc"):
        filenameOrig = filename
        src_path = os.path.join(cwd, filename)
        src_path_norm = os.path.normpath(src_path)
        doc = app.Documents.Open(src_path_norm)
        doc.Activate()
        docxPath = 'TEMP_CONVERTED_WORD_FILE_' + filename[:-4] + ".docx"
        dest_path = os.path.join(cwd, docxPath)
        dest_path_norm = os.path.normpath(dest_path)
        app.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(dest_path_norm, FileFormat=constants.wdFormatXMLDocument)
        doc.Close(False)
        filename = docxPath
    if filename.endswith(".docx"):
        src_path = os.path.join(cwd, filename)
        src_path_norm = os.path.normpath(src_path)
        doc = docx.Document(src_path_norm)
        chars = sum(len(p.text) for p in doc.paragraphs) + sum(len(p.text) for section in doc.sections for hf in [section.header, section.footer] for p in hf.paragraphs)
        charCounts[filenameOrig if filenameOrig else filename] = chars / 65
charCounts = {k:charCounts[k] for k in sorted(charCounts)}

# uses openpyxl package
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws.cell(row=1, column=2, value='File Name')
ws.cell(row=1, column=4, value='chars/65')
for i, x in enumerate(charCounts):
    ws.cell(row=i + 3, column=2, value=x[:-4] if x.endswith('.doc') else x[:-5])
    ws.cell(row=i + 3, column=4, value=charCounts[x])
ws.cell(row=len(charCounts) + 3, column=3, value='Total')
ws.cell(row=len(charCounts) + 3, column=4, value=sum(charCounts.values()))
path = './charCounts.xlsx'
wb.save(path)
```

Explanation:

- For every file with name ending in `.docx` except those starting with `TEMP_CONVERTED_WORD_FILE_`, store character count (divided by 65) by filename as key in a dictionary `charCount`
- For every file ending in `.doc`, use the `pywin32` package of Win32 extensions to convert it to a `.docx` file with `TEMP_CONVERTED_WORD_FILE_` prepended to the filename, then store character count (divided by 65) by its original filename as key in the same dictionary as above
- Replace the `charCounts` dictionary with one that has insertion order by the filename key
- Iterate through `charCounts` storing the contents in an Excel file, taking care to truncate the `.doc` or `.docx` suffix from the filename key.

Comment: ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(19, LCID, 1, (13, 0), ((16396, 1), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17)),FileName
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Word', 'Sorry, we couldn\'t find your file. Was it moved, renamed, or deleted?\r ("C:\\...\\abcbaxyz.doc")', 'wdmain11.chm', 24654, -2146823114), None)

Comment: It is showing like this :- pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Word', 'Sorry, we couldn\'t find your file. Was it moved, renamed, or deleted?\r ("C:\\Users\\myname\\Onedrive\\abcbaxyz.doc")'

Comment: Why is it going to onedrive ?

Comment: See my updated answer which adds character counts from headers and footers and also attempts to rely less on relative paths. This should fix the issues you were seeing (let me know if it doesn't).

Comment: Why is'nt this accurate? When i count all the characters manually and divide by 65, the character count is more than that of python. If i press alt+t+w, then it shows character count with spaces. if i divide by 65, i am getting a more number than python tool. i want my python tool to be like exact.

Comment: This tool is not counting bullets and tabs. i want those also to be counted.

Comment: I dont want header and footer. remove header and footer count. But i want every single character to be counted including bullets, tabs, whatever they are but i dont want header and footer

Comment: I'm really not sure of the exact mapping between character count reporting within the Microsoft Word application and the python-docx API for the particular files you're looking at. If you want to upload some files to a google drive share (for example) for which you're seeing discrepancies, that would allow at least an analysis of reconciling these two distinct metrics. Otherwise my answers should give you plenty of pointers to the packages/libraries that are out there to deal with Word files from python. You may need to do the final work of finetuning and reconciliation on your end.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1b5tgDTHNalq8my3Wg8pdl0ysAizZfWZJ/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100838328558767878200&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: I downloaded this as a `.doc` file with the "Word Count" dialog box showing these Statistics: Pages 1, Words 166, Characters (no spaces) 868, Characters (with spaces) 1,042, Paragraphs 21, Lines 29. Please confirm this is what you're seeing on your end.

Comment: Yes. I am also exactly seeing like that.

Comment: The python should also divide characters(with spaces) / 65 and store it in a word document.

Comment: Is there any way that the string "TOTAL" and the int(total numbers) can be in bold ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246183/discussion-between-constantstranger-and-cyper-python).

Comment: Making a cell bold can be done like this: `ws.cell(row, column).font = Font(bold=True)`.

Comment: I also added some comments and a link to some updated code [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246183/discussion-between-constantstranger-and-cyper-python).

Comment: return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1105, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((16396, 17), (16396, 17), (16396, 17)),SaveChanges
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147418111, 'Call was rejected by callee.', None, None)

Comment: Can you add a line which removes the files which startswith TEMP_CONVERTED_WORD_FILE_

Comment: Can i get the character count in excel only 2 digits after decimal. I meant, after point only 2 digits i want.

Comment: To remove a file, you can use [`os.remove(file_name)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove). To change the numeric format of a cell in an Excel worksheet, you can do this: `cell.number_format = '0.00'` using one of the [number formats](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/styles/numbers.html) available in openpyxl.